# django comments not visible on site

Tags: python, html, django

I am doing a Django project and I added a functionality where users can post comments. However, that functionality isn't visible on my test site. Here is the function add_comment and what I imported in my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from article.models import Article, Comment
from django.http import HttpResponse
from forms import ArticleForm, CommentForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.utils import timezone

#import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
# Create your views here.



  def add_comment(request, article_id):
    a = Article.objects.get(id=article_id)

    if request.method == "POST":
        f = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if f.is_valid():
            c = f.save(commit=False)
            c.pub_date = timezone.now()
            c.article = a
            c.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/articles/get/%s' % article_id)
    else:
        f = CommentForm()

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['article'] = a
    args['form'] = f 

    return render_to_response('add_comment.html', args)
```

In my INSTALLED_APPS section of settings.py I have:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.comments',
    'article',
)
```

And my add_comment.html file:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block sidebar %}
<ul>
    <li><a href="/articles/get/{{article.id}}">Cancel</a></li>
</ul>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<form action="/articles/add_comment/{{article.id}}/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<ul>
{{form.as_ul}}
</ul>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post Comment">
</form>

   {% endblock %}
```

I don't get any error messages. The comments section is missing and I don't know why. I ran

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

in the Ubuntu terminal also. I'd appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Does your base.html define a "content" block?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman: My base.html does.

Comment: Ah, but your normal article view doesn't provide "form" to the template, does it?

Comment: I don't understand. Are you referring to add_comment.html or base.html?

Comment: I wasn't referring to any templates at all. I was referring to the `article` view, which you have removed in your latest edit. Are you saying that the form is not showing when you go to the add_comment URL?

Comment: It shows, however I wanted there to be a link to the add_comments page on the test page article itself.

Comment: OK, then I don't understand what that has to do with all the code you have posted. Why don't you just put `{% url 'add_comment' article_id=article.id %}` on the article page?

Comment: I just needed to modify articles.html. Thank you.